# Theorem boxes in beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems

Usually I use beamer  with the Warsaw theme which puts theorems (and other things) in boxes. Now I switched my theme to Marburg but i still want to keep the boxes. How can one do that?

Comment: There are many similar questions on TeX.SX such as [Beamer newenvironment for theorems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62600) an [Redefine block template for Beamer theorem-like environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71265).

Comment: @Andrew I am looking for something really simple - I just want the boxes back, that's all. I don't really want to start redefining things if it can be avoided...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In fact even using the `Marburg` theme, your theorems are still in boxes, but you do not see them, because their colours are undefined. `Warsaw` uses colours from the `orchid` colour theme, so you can just add it to your presentation as well.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Marburg}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{A theorem in a box}
        \begin{theorem}
         Let $r, s$ be integers such that gcd$(r, s)=1$. 
        Given integers $a,b$, there exists unique 
        $x <rs$ such that 
        \end{theorem} 
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]